# Button click on enter press JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
  
  $("#AddDataStavka, #AddDataRazmer").on("keyup", function (event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("tr.trNewLine").children().first().children().first().get(0).click();
    }
});

/*This is code inside a document.ready, what I'm trying to do is call this every time a button is pressed and if its the enter key it should click the button.
What am I doing wrong?

Here's what I'm trying to target:*/
```

```html
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

            <tr runat="server" id="trNewLine" class="trNewLine" visible="false">
                <td runat="server" id="operationCol3">
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="btnAddDataAdd" runat="server" class="btn btn-pireus" OnClick="btnAddAddData_Click" ToolTip="Добави застраховка"><span>Добавяне</span></asp:LinkButton></td>
                <td>
                    <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="AddDataType" class="DropDownListHint" data-taggle="dropdown" data-style="DropDownListHint-datastyle" OnSelectedIndexChanged="AddDataType_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:DropDownList>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-pireus" id="AddDataStavka" clientidmode="static" onchange="glowInsuranceCheck()" runat="server" maxlength="15" text=''>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <select class="DropDownListHint" id="AddDataRisk" runat="server" data-placement="top" data-taggle="dropdown" data-style="DropDownListHint-datastyle"></select>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-pireus bst-suma" id="AddDataRazmer" clientidmode="static" onchange="glowInsuranceCheck()" runat="server" maxlength="19">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <select class="DropDownListHint" id="AddDataInsurer" runat="server" data-placement="top" data-taggle="dropdown" data-style="DropDownListHint-datastyle"></select>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <select class="DropDownListHint" id="AddDataInsured" runat="server" data-placement="top" data-taggle="dropdown" data-style="DropDownListHint-datastyle"></select>
                </td>
            </tr>
```

Comment: Ok. So what is not working? What is the question? besides the `e` which is *undefined* What button are you trying to click?

Comment: e.preventDefault(); isn't acutally doing anything and it's clicing another button.

Comment: use `event.preventDefault();` instead of `e.preventDefault();` because in your code the `e` is not defined.

Comment: take a look on your browser console, you will see errors there

Comment: do u want to trigger it on button press?

Answer (score 1):

as per your event handler function, `e.preventDefault` is wrong use `event` instead

```js
  
  $("#AddDataStavka, #AddDataRazmer").on("keyup", function (event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $("tr.trNewLine").children().first().children().first().focus().trigger("click");
    }
});

/*This is code inside a document.ready, what I'm trying to do is call this every time a button is pressed and if its the enter key it should click the button.
What am I doing wrong?

Here's what I'm trying to target:*/
```

```html
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

            <tr runat="server" id="trNewLine" class="trNewLine" visible="false">
                <td runat="server" id="operationCol3">
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="btnAddDataAdd" runat="server" class="btn btn-pireus" OnClick="btnAddAddData_Click" ToolTip="Добави застраховка"><span>Добавяне</span></asp:LinkButton></td>
                <td>
                    <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="AddDataType" class="DropDownListHint" data-taggle="dropdown" data-style="DropDownListHint-datastyle" OnSelectedIndexChanged="AddDataType_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:DropDownList>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-pireus" id="AddDataStavka" clientidmode="static" onchange="glowInsuranceCheck()" runat="server" maxlength="15" text=''>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <select class="DropDownListHint" id="AddDataRisk" runat="server" data-placement="top" data-taggle="dropdown" data-style="DropDownListHint-datastyle"></select>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-pireus bst-suma" id="AddDataRazmer" clientidmode="static" onchange="glowInsuranceCheck()" runat="server" maxlength="19">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <select class="DropDownListHint" id="AddDataInsurer" runat="server" data-placement="top" data-taggle="dropdown" data-style="DropDownListHint-datastyle"></select>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <select class="DropDownListHint" id="AddDataInsured" runat="server" data-placement="top" data-taggle="dropdown" data-style="DropDownListHint-datastyle"></select>
                </td>
            </tr>
```

Comment: I tried this and it's still not preventing the default.

Comment: @AlexanderHristov, check your console, maybe there are errors, and that's why the `.preventDefault()` is not even executing.

Comment: There's nothing inside the console, and it's not going into the event at all when I'm using debugger; Should I keep this code inside the document.ready?

Comment: @AlexanderHristov looks like the next line has some error, `$("tr.trNewLine").children().first().children().first().get(0)` is undefined.

Comment: I've changed it to this.

$("tr.trNewLine").children().first().children().first().focus().trigger("click");

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code instead. Use `keydown/keypress` event on the elements.

```
$('body').on("#AddDataStavka, #AddDataRazmer", "keydown", function (event) {
        if (event.keyCode == 13) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $("tr.trNewLine").children().first().children().first().get(0).click();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Same result, it's not reaching the function at all.

Comment: EDIT: It still didn't work tried both inside and outside the document.ready.

Answer (score 0):

Try with selecting #btnAddDataAdd directly:

```
$("#AddDataStavka, #AddDataRazmer").keypress(function (e){
  if (e.which === 13) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $("#btnAddDataAdd"").click();
  };
})
```

Comment: I've tried selecting it directly, it worked. The problem is it's inside an updatepanel and giving it clientidmode="static" makes it do a fullpostback.

Comment: And did you make 'btnAddAddData_Click' function? Just add this keypress event for Enter click inside that function.

Comment: Do you mean in c#?

Comment: No, with jquery. Like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/rem7gpd6/1/), but then inside that function, you have to add what you want to happen when the button (enter) is pressed, assuming you want to add some data. And you have to add onclick="clickBtn()"